# Async HostBinding in directive

Tags: angular

I'm looking for the best way to handle HostBinding with async value.

Before Angular **v2.1.2** I could use the `host` property in the `@Directive` decorator like that :

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'img[my-directive]',
    host    : {
        '[alt]'  : "alt | async"
    }
})
export class MyDirective {
    alt: Observable<string>;
}
```

But it looks like this was not the intended behavior, since version 2.1.2 fixes it. See [don't access view local variables nor pipes in host expressions](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/867494a).

Now, when compiling with AoT compilation, I get `Parser Error: Host binding expression cannot contain pipes in Directive`.

Comment: What host property are you trying to bind to? Can you give us the code of the host element?

Comment: The host element is a native `<img>`. I want `MyDirective` to asynchronously bind the value of the `alt` observable property to the `alt` img attribute.

Comment: "... we never wanted to have pipes in host bindings." Source: [Async Host Binding No Longer Works 12671](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12671#issuecomment-258168242) So you should find another way to do this, or update your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tobias Bosch (member of the Angular team) writes:

> Host bindings of a component ("child") are executed in the component
> that uses that component ("parent"). And the parent component can
> belong to a different NgModule. So if you use a pipe, the pipe is
> resolved against the NgModule of the parent component. However, if
> that NgModule does not declare the pipe that you are using, your
> component is broken.
>
> This is the reason why we never wanted to have pipes in host bindings.
> After one of the bigger compiler refactorings before 2.0 final, we
> accidentally reintroduced it, but this was a bug, not a feature, as
> the semantics are wrong.

Source:

[Async Host Binding No Longer Works #12671](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12671#issuecomment-258168242)

There also is an open ticket to use Observables with HostBindings:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19483

Comment: Ok so forget PIPES. What about OBSERVABLES? Why can't it just look at the value, check `isObservable(...)` and act accordingly? As you get more and more comfortable with RxJS this is one of the biggest missing links to get everything working nicely together. I'd LOVE it to just be automatic when i create a HostBinding to automatically subscribe if `Observable.isObservable()` returns true. Host binding is already 'magic' right!?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there is no special way to do it. You need to explicitly assign to the property

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'img[my-directive]',
    host    : {
        '[alt]'  : "alt"
    }
})
export class MyDirective {
    altObservable: Observable<string>;
    alt: string;

    subscription:Subscription;    

    ngOnInit() {
      this.subscription = this.altObservable.subscribe(val => this.alt = val)
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
      this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Ensure you unsubscribe subscriptions you create imperatively.

Comment: Pipe outside the template was never supposed to work. (perhaps in some pre-beta times). I found it interresting that it worked until recently.

Comment: You could try using `AsyncPipe.transform()` directly. Perhaps with `ngDoCheck()` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/745e10e6d2ea9097b7ec650ae54cea91e3d193f2/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts

Comment: They are thinking about better observable integration for the next Angular2 versions. I'm sure they'll come up with something new eventually.

Comment: I would be nice to mention that if you use the explicit assignment to a property, you're now responsible for unsubscribing from the `Observable`. I suppose many people especially less experienced ones could easily miss that part.