# Can I access host-bindings some other way than through @HostBinding?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

My underlying problem is I need to set an asynchronous function that [alters an attribute of the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462884/async-hostbinding-in-directive).  Since @HostBinding has no asynchronous abilities, I set a instance variable on the component, bound that, and manually maintained that variable.  To get it to work without the infamous ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, I needed to do this

```
@Component(...) 
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  constructor(private readonly cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  @Input() inputObservable: Observable<boolean>;
  @HostBinding('class.some-class') private setCssClass: boolean;

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.inputObservable.do(v => {
      if (this.setCssClass !== v) {
        setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setCssClass = v;
                    this.cdr.detectChanges();
                  }, 0);
     }
   })
   .subscribe();
  }
}
```

which is just awful.

Is there some cleaner way to tell the parent "here's a new value for one of your variables, set it at your leisure"?

**EDIT:**

*And* it doesn't even work.  That setTimeout can, under special circumstances, execute after the component has officially been destroyed, which causing an exception needs an whole 'nother level of hacky horribleness to prevent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply go for the `Renderer` with `ElementRef` approach. And don't forget to unsubscribe from your Observable once the component is destroyed:

```
@Component(...) 
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @Input() 
  public inputObservable: Observable<boolean>;

  private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject<void>()

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputObservable
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .do(v => this.toggleClass('some-class', v))
      .subscribe()
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

  private toggleClass(klass: string, state: boolean) {
    if(!this.element.nativeElement) return;
    if(state) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, klass)
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.element.nativeElement, klass)
    }
  }
}
```

A second approach would be to change the input of you component to a `boolean` and then from the parent component input the observable with `async`-pipe:

```
@Input()
@HostBinding('class.some-class')
public myInput: boolean;
```

**Parent component**

```
<my-component [myInput]="myObservable$ | async"></my-component>
```

Comment: Hahahaha.  I posted the edit 22 minutes ago, and was forced to go back to Google and spent the intervening time finding that exact solution.  I returned to Stackoverflow to answer my own question.

Comment: Yes, it works.  I'm not unsubscribing because I'm not subscribing: I'm passing the Observables to the template, which uses `| async`, which is supposed to take care of the unsubscription itself.

Comment: Yep for the second approach you don't need to  unsubscribe anything.

Comment: No, I mean, the Observable was already being used in the component's template.  No offense meant, but I really don't like the second solution: it doesn't give the child component a good sense of what is really going on (and if the Observable can emit null, cannot distinguish between that null and "waiting").