# Angular HostBinding an Observable?

Tags: angular

I have inherited a component which takes a configuration input and sets a style hostbinding for opacity.

```js
  @Input() config: IShellBackgroundColor;
  @HostBinding('style.opacity') 
  get opacity() {
    return this.config?.opacity;
  }
```

In a refactor of it, I was looking to drive this from an observable instead.

```js
  @HostBinding('style.opacity') 
  get opacity() {
    return this.shellBackgroundColorQuery.opacity$;
  }

  constructor( 
    private readonly shellBackgroundColorQuery: ShellBackgroundColorQuery
  ) {}
```

I appeciate that I am going from a `number` to an `Observable<number>` here.

**Question:**

What are my options? If I cannot use `HostBinding`, is there an alternative solution to style the host that would be compatible with observables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462884/async-hostbinding-in-directive

Comment: Thanks enno! I suppose it does but it sucks a lot!